# Mongoose aggregate multiple nested arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 schemas:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String
    },
    tasks:{
        type:[mongoose.Types.ObjectId]
    }
})
```

```
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String
    },
    finished:{
        type: Boolean
    },
    deadline:{
        type:Date
    },
    subtasks:{
        type:[mongoose.Types.ObjectId]
    }
})
```

```
const subtaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String
    },
    finished:{
        type: Boolean
    },
    deadline:{
        type:Date
    },
})
```

I would like to perform a query that would return something like this:

```
{
        "_id": "id",
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password",
        "tasks": [
            "_id": "id",
            "title": "title",
            "deadline": "deadline",
             "finished": false,
            "subtasks": [
                         {
                          "_id": "id",
                          "title": "title",
                          "deadline": "deadline",
                          "finished": false
                         }
                        ]

        ]
}
```

To my understading, aggregate should do this but I'm not quite sure how to handle nested arrays with it. I know that relational DBs would suit this better, but this is the situation I am currently in. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might not need an aggregate since your user schema already has tasks as an array in them, so you could just call "populate" on the user records via mongoose. Take a look at this for example https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

in your `userSchema`, add `ref: 'task'` or anything you name to your `task model` to point it in your task collection.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String
    },
    tasks:{
        type:[mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'task'
    }
})
```

same thing you to your `taskSchema`, add `ref: 'subtask'` or whatever you name in your subtask collection.

```
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type: String
    },
    finished:{
        type: Boolean
    },
    deadline:{
        type:Date
    },
    subtasks:{
        type:[mongoose.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'subtask'
    }
})
```

with that you could your `populate` function rather than `aggregate`

```
let populateQuery = [{ path: "task", select: "", populate: { path: "subtask", select: "" } }];
```

in that case we are have nested populate since `subtask` is a field in `task`

```
let populateQuery = [{ path: "task", select: "", populate: { path: "subtask", select: "" } }];

let users = await Users.find({}).populate(populateQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using the populate method as suggested

```
userSchema.find({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.userId)}).populate({
        path: 'tasks',
        populate: { path: 'subtasks' }
      })
```